# How to Regex remove multiple invalid characters in powershell?

Tags: powershell-3.0, sharepoint-online

I am new to PowerShell and I would like to know if there is a way to remove specific occurrences of invalid characters using PowerShell?

/RAM-_Tranva-_Bi.pdf - In this instance I would very much like to remove the "-__" from the filename.

/us-LRT---Atten.pdf  - In this instance I would like to remove the "---" from the filename

I have tried:

-replace [-]+, ""

-replace -[3], ""

-replace "[#%*:<>?/|-_]", ""

Doesn't seem to work either way...

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 0):

Your trouble is that you have to enclose your values into single quotes try :

```
"/RAM-_Tranva-_Bi.pdf"  -replace '[-]+',''
```

or :

```
"/us-LRT---Atten.pdf "  -replace '[-]+',''
"/us-LRT---Atten.pdf "  -replace '[-]3',''
```

Answer (score -1):

I finaly figured out something different.

```
$destinationUrl = [string]::Format("{0}{1}", $destinationList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, (($item.FullName.Replace($rootPath, "") -replace "[#%*:<>?/|]") -replace "[\\]", "/"));
```

Works like a charm and saves me tons of lines of code where I have to take into account every single thing going wrong.

Comment: I don't understand, you were missing quotes using the -replace operator and you give a turn around as an answer ?

Comment: I never use quotes as it is time consuming and not needed.

Comment: You just can see that it works with these single qotes as you ask for.